# Image overlay: what does `defimage` do and how to make it work as expected?

Tags: images, overlays

After solving the problem with appropriate height of placement of the as overlay inserted image ( see [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/76881/40171) "Image overlay: how to change the relative image insert position within the buffer text?" ):

[image]

I wanted to improve the code and replaced `setq img (create-image ...` with `defimage img ...` but it does not work as expected. If I use the `img` symbol from `defimage` I am not getting the image displayed.

The documentation, if I understand it right, tells me that `defimage` sets the symbols value to `image description` which is the same as what it tells to be returned by `create-image`, but somehow it seems that the effect when using it is another one.

**What does `defimage` actually do and how to make the symbol it sets to work as an image?**

Below code you can copy/paste to the *Scratch* buffer and run it to see yourself that changing the variable name representing the image to this one set by `defimage` results in not displaying the overlay image anymore (see `;; <<<### remove '-var' here` in the below code how to activate use of the not working symbol from `defimage`).

```
;; =====================================================================
;;    Replace special Unicode character "ä" with an Emacs logo image
;; ---------------------------------------------------------------------
;; ______________________________
;; Emacs ämacs ämacs ämacs Emacs
;; ------------------------------
;; ä y^T ä Q^g ä Ö_É ä j_ą ä Xy
;; ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
(defvar regex-UnicodeEmacsLogoChar "ä")
(setq-default case-fold-search nil);; nil -> sensitive  t -> ignore case
(setq imgFileName "emacs_logo-round_icon_16x16.png")
;; ---------------------------------
(setq max-image-size 128);; load images up to size of 128x128 pixel
;;   'max-image-size' <- variable <- src/image.c (default 10.0) 
;;       ^-- if float -> % of frame width/height 
;;       ^-- if int   -> width/height pixel
;;       ^-- if nil   -> no size limit
(defvar img-emacsLogo-16x16-var 
  (create-image imgFileName  
  ;  v-- TYPE  v--DATA-P : infer type from ".png" : no img data symbol 
    nil       nil    
    :transform-smoothing t 
    :ascent  'center ;; 'center or value in range 0-100 (%)
    :scale   1.0     ;; -> scales :width/height (keeps max-width/height)
    ;; :pointer 'hourglasss ;; text or nil ("I"-like shape) arrow vdrag
    )
);defvar img-emacsLogo-16x16-var
;; ---
(defimage img-emacsLogo-16x16 ((
    :type png ;; ( pbm xbm xpm gif jpeg tiff png svg ) or imagemagick  
    :file imgFileName ;; looks for the file in 'image-load-path'
    ;; :file XOR :data <- a string with image data
    :transform-smoothing t 
    :ascent center ;; symb. 'center or 0-100(% height) default 50
    ;; :margin     ;; around -> int (horiz . vert) in pixels (0 . 0)  
    ;; :relief     ;; shadow in pixel 0, minus -> pressed button look
    ;; :width      ;; scale the image to given values preserving
    ;; :height     ;; ... the aspect ratio if it is necessary to 
    ;; :max-width  ;; ... limit its size to given values of maximal
    ;; :max-height ;; ... width and height
    :scale   1.0   ;; -> scales :width/height (keeps max-width/height)
    ;; :rotation   ;; 90,180,270 deg or any value if imagemagick type
    ;; :index      ;; frame See Multi-Frame images
    ;; :conversion ;; algorithm: laplace emboss disabled ...
    ;;          (edge-detection :matrix matrix :color-adjust adjust)
    ;; :mask       ;; mask (see: Image-Descriptors.html for details)
    :pointer hourglasss ;; text or nil ("I"-like shape) arrow vdrag
    ;;                      modeline hand hdrag nhdrag hourglasss
    ;; :map ;; alist -> (area id plist) see Image-Descriptors.html 
    ;;      define mouse pointer interaction areas and responses
    ;;      avail.: rect, circle, poly
)));defimage img-emacsLogo-16x16
;; ---
(defun font-lock-add-keywords_UnicodeEmacsLogoChar (&optional limit)
  (when (re-search-forward  regex-UnicodeEmacsLogoChar  limit    t )
    ;;   ^-- start at point  regex_string --^          BOUND  NO-ERROR  COUNT=1
    (setq  beg  (match-beginning  0) ;; 0 -> which regex capt. group? 
           end  (match-end        0)
           str  (match-string     0)
    );set the above values first then create an overlay
    (setq        ov (make-overlay  beg end))
    (overlay-put ov 'display       img-emacsLogo-16x16-var) ;; <<<### remove '-var' here
    (overlay-put ov 'face          'default)
    (overlay-put ov 'evaporate     1   )
    (message "nextOverlay for \"%s\" beg %s  end %s "  str beg end)
  )
)
(font-lock-add-keywords 
    nil ;; 'emacs-lisp-mode ;; MODE: nil -> curr. buffer ( lisp-mode emacs-lisp-mode python-mode ... )  
    ;; KEYWORDS -> here list with keyword MATCHER function:
    '((font-lock-add-keywords_UnicodeEmacsLogoChar (0 'font-lock-keyword-face t)))
    t ;; HOW
)
```

Here [image] the logo image you see in the upper image.

Be warned that there are many other issues related to the code above which need to be fixed:

- It works only from the cursor position down "on demand"
- If I specify only the image name setting appropriate image search path it does not load the image *(use a full path image name if the code above does not show the overlay with the image)*.
- It generates probably unnecessary a huge amount of overlays overlying present ones (does it?) on each redraw of the screen
- ... and so on ... but ... *one question per question* so let's fix the issue with `defimage img` first (which is in my eyes much cleaner syntax compared to `(setq img create-image`).

By the way: you can use the code above as a kind of documentation. It puts together the essence of all the information in the documentation and demonstrates how it works (or doesn't).

---

% UPDATE: I have changed the code back to what I had started with seeing that it does not work. Now the code is updated with the in the comments and the answer suggested changes. Sorry for the inconvenience.

%% UPDATE: I have changed `'ascent` to `ascent` and `'hourglass` to `hourglass` as `defimage` did else not work in other context provided in comments and the answer, but the problem with not displayed image is still not solved by these changes.

Comment: The doc string of `defimage` says: `All specifications must at
least contain the properties ‘:type TYPE’ and either ‘:file FILE’ or
‘:data DATA’`, but `:type` is commented out above. You are also missing a set of parens: see the example in  the doc string.

Comment: I had already the type defined and the double parens there (which are not necessary because the example in the documentation lists *two* possible configurations and I have only one), but it didn't work Changed it back and tested again - it doesn't change the fact that the image is not displayed.

Comment: `...which are not necessary because the example in the documentation lists two possible configurations and I have only one` - you are wrong to think that.

Comment: `it doesn't change the fact that the image is not displayed`: then there are more problems, but that does not mean that the above are *not* problems. In any case, if you want to avoid misunderstandings then you have to describe *everything* you did, not post the last code you tried and wait for us to guess what you tried but have not shown.

Comment: Sorry for posting the wrong code. Just forget to set it back to what it should be according to the documentation. Seeing that it does not work I have tried this and that ... and then forgot that I have changed it.

Answer (score 0):

[Expanding the comment]

The doc string of `defimage` says: `All specifications must at least contain the properties ‘:type TYPE’ and either ‘:file FILE’ or ‘:data DATA’`, but :type is commented out above. You are also missing a set of parens: it should be:

```el
(defimage img-emacsLogo-16x16 ((:type png
                                :file imgFileName         
                                :transform-smoothing t 
                                :ascent 'center
                                :scale   1.0
                                :pointer 'hourglass)))
```

The `SPECS` parameter is a list of property lists: `Each image specification in SPECS is a property list`.

Untested.

EDIT: The testing harness that you have is much too heavy. You should start with something lighter. E.g.

```el
(defimage img-emacsLogo-16x16 ((
    :type png
    :file "/tmp/emacs-logo.png"
    :transform-smoothing t)))


(insert-image img-emacsLogo-16x16)
```

works for me. But when I add `:ascent 'center` to the property list, it does not work any more. That's because of the quote: `:ascent center` works. I haven't checked, but that's probably because `defimage` is a macro that does not evaluate the SPECS argument.

Comment: Now tested ... but does not work.

Comment: `:pointer 'hourglass` does not work either as it should, because there is no `hourglass` but usual pointer (so it results in not showing the I-beam anymore).

Comment: Removed `:hourglass` and `:ascent` but it still does not work. Will now test your code.

Comment: Your code works for me in `*Scratch*` buffer OK when using without the quotation.