# Image overlay: how to write code scaling overlay images along with the text?

Tags: images, overlays

See the code in [my other question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/76891/40171) which places an image overlay above a special character:

[image]

The problem with this code is that the images don't get scaled along with the text:

[image]

**How to write code scaling overlay images along with the text?**

Comment: When scaling text, it will be necessary to programmatically visit each overlay and put a new `'display` property with a different image that is resized using `create-image`.  A few images with different sizes can be created and reused, or new images with the desired size can be created on an as-need basis.  It may be helpful to create a minimal working example that does *not* use `font-lock` to place the overlays ...  Once you have resolved that, then move towards the next step -- if that absolutely must be done with `font-lock` or some other method, such as a `post-command-hook` ....

Comment: What about imagemagick? I have compiled Emacs with support for imagemagick in the hope it can automate all the resizing work on images, but don't (yet) know how to use it. What I am wondering about is how it comes that I can't find online any code to copy/paste which does just that. Hmmm ...

Comment: This is much too complicated to copy and paste code.  A decision needs to be made regarding how and when the overlays will be placed, modified, moved, deleted, etc.  And, decisions will need to be made regarding optimization (depending upon the extent to which overlays are used and the size of the buffer, or limiting the work to the visible windows).  If you like Imagemagick, then perhaps have a look at some Emacs libraries that use that back-end and see if something there might be of use to you.  I don't have any suggestions in that regard.